# Bash call another script depending on "read" input

Tags: bash

I am trying to learn about making simple bash scripts to do things on my computer just because I want to learn because I think it is interesting (and I can also think of uses down the track).

I am trying to write a script that assigns variables that will call another script depending on what I type.  I have managed to call another script from a variable using the below:

```
#!/bin/bash
Echo hello please choose you next step
VBA="/Users/zap/VBA.sh"
$VBA
```

but now I want to be able to call one script or another depending on user input, and I have tried to make the script below, so that if when I type VBA in the "read" section it runs one script and if I type in VBB in it runs a different script.  But it seems that this does not work how do I need to change the syntax to make the out put run with the script VBA or VBB?

```
#!/bin/bash
Echo hello please choose you next step
VBA="/Users/zap/VBA.sh"
VBB="/Users/zap/VBB.sh"
read IPT
NXT="$"$IPT""
echo $NXT
```

If I can make this work I will turn this into a simple script that runs `sudo shutdown` and then asks me if I want to shut down immediately (I think `-h`) or restart (I think `-r`).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.

1) You could use an if statement and explicitly run the command you want:

```
echo Do you want to reboot (Y/N)?
read IPT
if [ "$IPT" = "Y" ] ; then
       shutdown -h now
else
       shutdown -r now
fi
```

2) you can try to force the user to type the command.  It could be dangerous if you sudo
   since the user could type something you don't want to run.

```
echo do you want to run VBA or VBB?
read IPT
"/Users/zap/${IPT}.sh"
```

Comment: Thank you, I did both of these to learn - and have ultimately used the "if" version also putting in a variable to change the time of when it happens.